# Use local.properties in build.gradle with Github Secrets when using Actions

Tags: android, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin, github-actions, building-github-actions

I am trying to replace API keys located in local.properties with Github Secrets values when using Github Actions.

The key is declared as follows in local.properties:

```
sdk.dir=/Users/xxxxxxx/Library/Android/sdk
API_KEY="xxxxxx"
```

Then, in my build.gradle I get the property like this:

```
 buildTypes {

    Properties properties = new Properties()
    properties.load(project.rootProject.file('local.properties').newDataInputStream())
    def api = properties.getProperty('API_KEY')

    debug {
        buildConfigField 'String', "API_KEY", api
        resValue('string', "api", api)

               .....
```

Github Actions is then run to replace the value with a secret here:

```
  on:
  push:

jobs:
  unit_tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - name: set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Update Username from Secrets
        env:
          MOCK_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}
        run: echo API_KEY="$API_KEY" > ./local.properties

      - name: Assemble app debug APK
        run: bash ./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace

      - name: Unit tests
        run: ./gradlew test
```

However every time this action is run, the build fails with the following error:

> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
>   Parameter specified as non-null is null: method com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BuildType.resValue, parameter
>   value

The line it points to is the buildConfigField 'String', "API_KEY", api line.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a line wrong:

`MOCK_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}`

should be this:

`API_KEY: ${{ secrets.API_KEY }}`